# Command not found + white terminal

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm pretty new on ubuntu and I encounter a pretty problematic issue. I set it up correctly and everything was working but since this morning, I have pretty big issues with the bash terminal.

First of all, everything went white while all my inputs got colours to distinct the path from the commands etc.

And the most problematic issue is that the commands from the addons I've downloaded don't launch anymore, including airflow, conda, spyder etc.

```
    cd ~/airflow
    airflow webserver
airflow: command not found

    conda list
conda : command not found
```

So I have issues like command not found, while those same commands were launching yesterday

I've already tried looking on the .bashrc file but nothing seemed strange in there.

If anyone has a hint that could save me from this nightmare!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well after looking pretty closely into other replies, turns out the color problem was a delink from the bashrc, it was solved using `source ~/.bashrc`, but my airflow server is still unrecognized

And after a lot of efforts I found the problem with the command not found, it was a problem of PATH that was never going into anaconda, where all the stuff I wanted to launch was.

A simple `export PATH=$PATH:/home/florentin/anaconda3/bin/` closed the deal !